# select items from first group in collection LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

I create card game in c# and i have following class, containing PlayerIDs, card sets from each player and two most powerfull cards:

```
public class ResultsList
{
    public int PlayerID = -1;
    public int Set = -1;
    public int Figure1 = -1;
    public int Figure2 = -1;
}
```

program creates list of results:

```
List<ResultsList> Results = new List<ResultsList>();
```

and next sorts it by Set, next by Figure1 and next by Figure2, so i get follownig list (example):

```
PlayerID       Set       Figure1         Figure2
0              2         2               1
1              2         2               1
3              1         1               0
```

It means that players "0" and "1" have same sets and figures, I want to put them both IDs in new list

```
List<int> Winers= new List<int>();
```

But in following case, "0" is the only one winner:

```
PlayerID       Set       Figure1         Figure2
0              2         3               1
1              2         2               1
3              1         1               0
```

So I want put only that ID into the results.
How do I do that?

Comment: How you judge winner by submission of Figure 1 and Figure 2?

Comment: Where is the code that you use to enter the winner into `List<int> Winers= new List<int>();`

Comment: Welcome to [so] btw, maybe take some time to read [ask] will help with this and future questions. As a first attempt though, not bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `Results` is ordered, you can use `First` to get the winner and then use `TakeWhile` to get all equal to it:

```
var winner = Results.First()
var winners = Results.TakeWhile(r => r.Set == winner.Set && r.Figure1 == winner.Figure1 && winner.Figure2 == r.Figure2).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for express response and for solution. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with `GroupBy`:

```
List<ResultsList> winners = 
    results.GroupBy(r => new {Set = r.Set, Figure1 = r.Figure1, Figure2 = r.Figure2}).
    OrderBy(g => g.Key.Set).
    ThenBy(g => g.Key.Figure1).
    ThenBy(g => g.Key.Figure2).
    First().ToList();
```

If `results` is already ordered you may ommit the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ResultsList> items = Results.OrderByDescending(item1 => 
        item1.Set).ThenByDescending(item2 => item2.Figure1).ThenByDescending(item3 =>
            item3.Figure2).ToList();

        ResultsList winner = items[0];
        List<int> winners = new List<int>();
        winners.Add(winner.PlayerID);
        winners.AddRange(items.Where((item, index) => 
            index > 0 && item.Set == winner.Set && 
            item.Figure1 == winner.Figure1 && 
            item.Figure2 == winner.Figure2)
            .ToList().Select(item=>item.PlayerID));
```